# React-Redux Provider not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My project uses React-Redux Provider.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

and

```js
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){

    API.getCategories().then((categories)=>{
      this.props.dispatch(addCategories(categories))
    })

    API.getAllPosts().then(posts => {
      console.log('getAllPosts', posts)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=>{
            return (
              <div>
                {
                  this.props.categories.map((category)=>{
                    return (
                          <Link key={category.name} to={`/category/${category.name}`} params={{category: category.name}} >{category.name}</Link>
                    )
                  })
                }
              </div>
            )
          }}
        />

        <Route path="/category/:category" component={Category} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(x) {

  return {
    categories: x.categories
  }
}

// export default App;

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(App))
```

From the above code and based on my experience from a previous project, the Category component's `this.props` should have a `dispatch` method that I can call the actions with but for some reason it is not there.

This is my Category Component:

```js
class Category extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('this.props of Category', this.props)

    var category = this.props.match.params.category

    API.getPosts(category).then((posts)=>{
      console.log('after getPosts', posts)
      this.props.dispatch(addAllPosts(posts))
    })
  }

  render(){
    return <p>Category</p>
  }
}

export default Category
```

What am I missing here???

Comment: It's not sufficient to just wrap a provider element, you need to create a container component around your category component that maps the state to the props and passes the dispatch function. See documentation: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `connect` function from `react-redux` on your `Category` component so it has [access to `dispatch`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-just-dispatch-and-dont-listen-to-store).

```
export default connect()(Category)
```

Also, it might just be simplified for SO, but `App` does not need to be wrapped in `withRouter`.  This is only required if you need the router props injected into the component.  `Route` does this automatically for any component it renders, which is why you don't need it on `Category`.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```